# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, iis, iis-8

I am creating application which stop the IIS Default Web Site. I used a PowerShell script to stop website because that script is executed form my website.

This is my script:

```
Import-Module C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration
Stop-Website 'Default Web Site'
my copy code
Start-Website 'Default Web Site'
```

And this is my C# code:

```
PowerShell _PowerShell = PowerShell.Create();

Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
rs.Open();

_PowerShell.Runspace = rs;
_PowerShell.AddScript(@"Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -scope LocalMachine").Invoke();
_PowerShell.AddScript(@"E:\DE.TEST\Power_Shell\Scripts\StopIISDefaultSite.ps1").Invoke();

if (_PowerShell.HadErrors)
{
    Collection<ErrorRecord> errors = _PowerShell.Streams.Error.ReadAll();

    foreach (var item in errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

It shows the following error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: I am using Any CPU. i am not master in powershell :(

Comment: i change it to x86. still error occurs.

Comment: clearly something is not registered on that machine (i.e COM component that needs to register in order for the code to execute against it)

Comment: @CodeCaster Seems to be the other way around, [you **need** to target x64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866150/powershell-new-webapplication)

Comment: Can we use Any CPU to execute this thing ?

Comment: If you're using a COM component, why not skip powershell and do it directly in C#? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21120/Stop-Start-IIS-Website-in-NET-C looks promising.

Comment: I want to stop my website form it`s own thread to update some files ?
Please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609910/stop-iis-website-from-its-own-thread/31610086#31610086

Comment: I also check in registry for the class {688eeee5-6a7e-422f-b2e1-6af00dc944a6}, that already registered. i am not clear about this, can we have to set any other key then default. because registry have only Default key.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to check whether the PowerShell instance you are running your PS code under is 32-bit or 64-bit and make your solution build for that target platform.
You can check this using:

```
if([IntPtr]::size -eq 8) { Write-Host 'x64' } else { Write-Host 'x86' }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588960/determine-if-current-powershell-process-is-32-bit-or-64-bit)

As pointed out in the comments setion, if you are running PowerShell 64-bit, building your solution for AnyCPU and unchecking "Prefer 32-bit" solves the issue.

Comment: Building for Any CPU with "Prefer 32-bit" unchecked seems to work for me (but I've only tested on a 64bit machine).

Answer (score 4):

Following on from @Jenish Zinzuvadiya's answer regarding PowerShell running as x86/x64, in my case the problem was that I was launching PowerShell from Visual Studio by using the "Open Command Line" plugin, which was launching PowerShell as an x86 process.

Launching PowerShell from the Start Menu did so as an x64 process and that resolved the problem for me.